CIris in point cloud environment
I'm working with IRIS-GCS motion planning for collision avoidance and trajectory optimization in a complex environment (specifically the vascular). The environment models are highly complex and non-convex. I found the original method for IRIS is to create collision geometry for obstacles in separate sdf file, such as the half_wall_vertical.sdf
<sdf version="1.5">
  <model name="Robot">
    <link name="Robot">
      <visual name="visual_Wall.019">
        <pose>0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 -1.57</pose>
        <geometry>
          <mesh>
            <uri>half_wall_vertical.obj</uri>
          </mesh>
        </geometry>
      </visual>
      <collision name="collision_Wall.019">
        <pose>0.0 0.0 0.75 0.0 0.0 0.0</pose>
        <geometry>
          <box>
            <size>0.25 5.0 1.5</size>
          </box>
        </geometry>
      </collision>
    </link>
    <frame name="frame_AboveHalfWall">
      <pose>0.0 0.0 2.25 0.0 0.0 0.0</pose>
    </frame>
  </model>
</sdf>

These collision geometries are created by simple geometry shapes. But a complicated vascular model composed of many simple convex shapes. So I wonder if there is any other method to handle the complicated model collision detection.
I'm think of using point cloud model, but didn't find functions for that. I found MeshcatPointCloudVisualizer to visualize point clouds and perception.PointCloud but they don't have the "Proximity role" as far as I know.

Do you mean the C-IRIS paper in https://arxiv.org/pdf/2302.12219 (which uses sum-of-squares optimization), or the IRIS-NP algorithm in https://arxiv.org/pdf/2303.14737 (which uses nonlinear nonconvex optimization)?
Neither approach supports point cloud directly, but you can either

Compute the convex hull of the point cloud as a mesh file, and use that mesh file.
Treat each point as a sphere with 0 radius.


Thanks for your reply! I'm willing to try both algorithms as stated there are tradeoffs. As for the mesh file, I originally planned to make a union of decomposed convex shapes of the original mesh as your first suggestion. But this would be quite expensive in my application. As for treating each point as a sphere, do you mean I can create a collision mesh for every point? If the radius is 0, would that be valid for collision detection? And would it be better if I set a very small value as the radius? Thank you very much for your help!

For C-IRIS paper, I would recommend do a convex decomposition of the original mesh file, as using points would be too expensive (I suppose you have many points). For the IRIS-NP algorithm, you can use both convex decomposition of the mesh and the small spheres approach. You can use spheres with very small radius.

thanks! It's true that processing both the point cloud and the decomposed mesh indeed are expensive, and this is the question I want to handle. I would try accordingly, thank you very much for your help!

Dear Hongkai, after finding that the deepnote is not enough for my project, I'm running on my pc. But I found that I can't import IrisInRationalConfigurationSpace from  pydrake.geometry.optimization anymore (pydrake on python 3.10).  I searched on drake's doc but didn't find notification about this neither on stackoverflow. Could you please suggest what happen?

Besides, when handling with the decomposed convex shape, I didn't find a way to include them in the sdf file. I konw drake has the GetConvexHull() function, but how could I use the output as what we did with simple geometry in the sdf file? As far as I'm concerned, I only know one way to include obstacles that is to write them in the sdf/ urdf file as what you did in your C-IRIS paper and the gcs-SR paper. Many thanks if your could give some suggestions!

Running IRIS-NP with the small spheres strategy on a point cloud will also probably be very expensive, since it will have to solve nonlinear programs for every single point in the point cloud. I would also recommend making a convex decomposition of the mesh.

You may find this tool useful for generating such convex decompositions: https://github.com/gizatt/convex_decomp_to_sdf
It will produce an SDF that you should be able to import directly.

thanks Thomas! That's a very helpful reference.
